# Как получить минимальное число из 5 предыдущих чисел вектора?

Tags: python, pandas, оптимизация, numpy, обработка-данных

Есть вектор с числами:

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([18, 4, 15, 14, 6, 7, 11, 12, 8, 5, 7, 0, 12, 0, 2, 18])
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
[nan nan nan nan  4.  4.  6.  6.  6.  5.  5.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

Решение с циклом:

```py
period = 5
lowest = np.full_like(arr, np.nan, dtype=float)

for i in range(period-1, len(arr)):
    lowest[i] = np.min(arr[i-(period-1) : i+1])
```

Можно ли получить векторизированным способом, без цикла?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

решение в Pandas - воспользуйтесь [Series.rolling(...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html):

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(arr)
res = s.rolling(5).min()
```

результат:

```
In [316]: res
Out[316]:
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     4.0
5     4.0
6     6.0
7     6.0
8     6.0
9     5.0
10    5.0
11    0.0
12    0.0
13    0.0
14    0.0
15    0.0
dtype: float64
```

или в виде `numpy.NDArray`:

```
In [317]: res.to_numpy()
Out[317]:
array([nan, nan, nan, nan,  4.,  4.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  5.,  5.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.])
```

Comment: Попробовал на чистом `Numpy` запилить - только забодался. Думал можно как-то тоже по простому )

Comment: @CrazyElf, https://stackoverflow.com/q/6811183/5741205 ;)